# Prove that graphs with no K4 minor are 2-degenerated.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that graphs with no K4 minor are 2-degenerated.

I can think about a counterexample for this statement.
Consider a vertex with 3 vertices adjacent to it, and these 3 vertices are not pairwise adjacent.

This graph has no K4 minor, but it is not 2-degenerated.

Comment: It's "2-degenerate" not "2-degenerated", and your example is: if you put the vertices in an order that puts the degree-3 vertex first, then every vertex has at most 2 neighbors that come before it.